# How to delete part of a line and keep the rest using Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, cut-command

Suppose that I have an output of lines like this:

```
First name, Last name, 123456789(9 digits)
GPA
Class
Major
University
```

How can I write some code to print the first 3 lines and only keep the ID number in the first line?

I tried to use `head`, `grep` and `cut`, but I wasn't able to do it.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use awk, to print the last comma-space separated field:

```
$ cat file
First name, Last name, 123456789
GPA
Class
Major
University

$ awk -F', ' 'NR<4 {print $NF}' file
123456789
GPA
Class
```

or sed to replace the longest string up to comma-space:

```
$ sed -n '1,3{s/.*, //; p}' file
123456789
GPA
Class
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple if-else statement also works with `awk`. In the following, we use comma-space as the field separator (`-F', '`) and print the 3rd field (`$3`) if we are on the first line (`NR == 1`), else the whole line (`$0`) for the first 3 lines (`NR < 4`) gets printed:

```
awk -F', ' '{if (NR == 1) print $3; else if (NR < 4) print $0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If your file has many such entries instead of just one, try :

```
cat file |tr "," "\n" |grep "[0-9]\{9\}" -A3
```